# Как вывести блок оплаты для конкретного товара WooCommerce PayPal Payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

WooCommerce PayPal Payments
Как вывести в принципе этот блок оплаты для каждого отдельного товара
У меня на сайте Wordpress WooCommerce. Стоит по рекомендации WooCommerce плагин для оплаты PayPal. У меня в теме в каждом товаре есть хуки  `'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form'`, `'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button'`, `'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button'`, `'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form'`.  В других темах кнопки PayPal выводятся вроде бы с этими хуками. Нужно ли что-то писать в function.php или использовать другие хуки